# Turbolinks Rails application Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget, turbolinks, stimulusjs, freshdesk

I am trying to use the Freshdesk widget in a Ruby on Rails turbolinks site.

Ever since I started using this widget, when navigating to other pages after the initial page load, I always get the following error in my console:

```
> VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'postMessage' of null
>     at Object.postMessage (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
>     at Object.widgetRenderComplete (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
>     at Object.handleMessage (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
```

This was my code Before adding a div with an id(a partial that i call it in my views with and ID as a variable)

```
<script>
  window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id': <%= widget_id %>
  };
  !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<%= widget_id %>.js' async defer></script>
```

View example

`<%= render "shared/freshdesk_widget", widget_id: 60000003593 %>`

I thought about using an **eventListener turbolinks:before-cache**, that looks for the div and remove it before-cache.

**This is how it looks now**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
    const deleteable = document.getElementById("div_to_delete");
    deleteable.parentNode.removeChild(deleteable);
  })
</script>

<div id="div_to_delete">
  <script>
    window.fwSettings={
      'widget_id': <%= widget_id %>
      };
      !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<%= widget_id %>.js' async defer></script>
</div>
```

Im facing two errors

```
> VM49956:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of
> null
>         at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:4:15)
>         at 
  Object../node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js.e.dispatch
> (turbolinks.js:5)
>         at r.notifyApplicationBeforeCachingSnapshot 
  (turbolinks.js:6)
>         at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks.js:6)
>         at r.cacheSnapshot (turbolinks.js:5)
>         at r.<anonymous> (turbolinks.js:5)
>         at turbolinks.js:5
```

And the same as before

```
> VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'postMessage' of null
>     at Object.postMessage (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
>     at Object.widgetRenderComplete (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
>     at Object.handleMessage (VM2797 <widget_id>.js:1)
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the element doesn't removes the widget in the DOM, so, as far i can see, what you have to do is to only initialize the widget only if the `window.FreshworksWidget` variable is undefined.

Replace all you code with just this lines:

```
<script>
if (window.FreshworksWidget === undenfined ) {
  window.fwSettings={
    'widget_id': <%= widget_id %>
  };
  !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
}
</script>
```